# How to safely remove/uninstall Android Virtual Device .img files added by Visual Studio Emulator for Android

Tags: android, visual-studio-2017

When the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 product is installed and the Cross-Platform Mobile Development workload is selected, it adds the Visual Studio Emulator for Android component, including a set of Android Virtual Devices (avd) folders (e.g. VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone.avd) contain some pretty large .img files. However, upon removing/uninstalling the "Visual Studio Emulator for Android" component from the product, it does not remove the AVDs and .img files. These are still left intact and consuming over 10GB of disk space.  So, question is how does one safely remove/uninstall the Android Virtual Device .img files without breaking something. Is direct deleting them from the filesystem, a safe option? Unfortunately, it does not appear on the Windows Control Panel's 'Add/Remove Programs' list. Thankful for any directions/possible suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Hyper-v Manager? Search in Cortana for Hyper-V Manager and execute it. You will see all the virtual devices listed out there.